# AJAX / javascript: parsing JSON that contains an array

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I'm trying to parse a JSON message that my page gets through an AJAX response however, it keeps throwing the following error and I have no clue why: 

"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element of the JSON data"

Here is what my page's javascript looks like:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
         var Response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    }
}
```

And here is what the JSON the server returns looks like:

```
{
    "Error": "",
    "ClientInfo": [{
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Bill"
    }, {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "Sally"
    }]
}
```

Any  idea what I'm doing wrong? JSON validators say it's valid JSON....

Comment: This is a valid JSON and it cannot cause that problem.

Comment: Did you get that JSON by inspecting the response from the server, or by another means?

Comment: Maybe `console.log(xhttp.responseText)` before parsing, then copy the console output and run that through your JSON checker; maybe the server inserts some error, or extra character somewhere?

Comment: @CharlSteynberg you are correct. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATE

It's that `Error:` key that's making the parser vomit it back out. See the demo.
Updated demo to include the JSON with `Error:` to compare results. Unfortunately, <del>I had to comment out</del> the console logged the `error` JSON because the debugger picked up on the `Script error` immediately. Fortunately, the demo still functions so you can ignore the initial error after loading.

### TEST 1

1. Try the `info` button first.    [<kbd>Result: Sally</kbd>]
2. Next click the `error0` button. [<kbd>Result: Sally</kbd>]
3. Then try the `error1` button.   [<kbd>Result: undefined</kbd>]

So it seems to parse if you:

1. Remove the `Error:""`
     OR
2. Place the `Error: ""` inside the array.

### TEST 2

Copy the `info` JSON then validate it. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

When you use JSONLint, you must strip it:

```
{
    "ClientInfo": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "Name": "Bill"
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "Name": "Sally"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now copy the `error` JSON and validate it.

```
{
    "Error": "",
    "ClientInfo": [{
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Bill"
    }, {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "Sally"
    }]
}
```

Both of them should be valid, yet the debugger and the parser reject the `error` JSON.

**Snippet**

```js
// Prepare JSON
var info =
  '{"ClientInfo": [' +
  '{"ID": 1, "Name": "Bill"},' +
  '{"ID": 2, "Name": "Sally"} ]}';

var error0 =
  '{"ClientInfo": [' +
  '{"ID": 1, "Name": "Bill"},' +
  '{"ID": 2, "Name": "Sally"},' +
  '{"Error": ""} ]}';


var error1 =
  '{"Error": ""},' +
  '{"ClientInfo": [' +
  '{"ID": 1, "Name": "Bill"},' +
  '{"ID": 2, "Name": "Sally"} ]}';


// Create a function that parses JSON Object

function JSONObj(json) {
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
  return jsonObj;
}

// A function that logs results one at a time so we can compare results

function processLog(result) {
  console.log('Result: ' + result);
}

/* Test info and errors */

var lastClient = JSONObj(info).ClientInfo[1].Name;

var errorA = JSONObj(error0).ClientInfo[1].Name;

var errorB = JSONObj(error1).ClientInfo[1].Name;
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <li>Remove this: <pre><code>"Error": "",</code></pre>
  </li>
  <li>Separate into segments (see script)</li>
  <li>Wrap each segment with single quotes `'`</li>
  <li>Add a `+` after each segment</li>
</ol>

<button onclick="processLog(lastClient);">info</button>
<button onclick="processLog(errorA);">error0</button>
<button onclick="processLog(errorB);">error1</button>
```

Comment: Even after removing the "Error" from my JSON message I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @Michael Did you see my demo? I'll update it with the `Error :` as well so you'll see.

Comment: ah. Interesting. I tried removing it, and resaving my work (maybe I didn't save something the first time) and now it goes through. So why exactly doesn't it like Error?

Comment: A Server might append an error to data because it perceives something that is an error. It could be anything, security, configuration, a bug, etc. hard to say. Do you always get JSONs with that error key? It might've been when you cut and pasted it that there was a zero space entity which is a ASCII char that's easily overlooked.

Answer (score -2):

Json parser takes in json string and parses it. You already have a json object

Comment: there's no such thing as a json object